# I didn't think you'd care about what I think/thought/would think of you

Tags: tense, past-tense, conditional-constructions

What form of the verb "think" should I use in the sentence *I didn't think you'd care about what I _____(think) of you.* to express "my" disbelief in "your" interest in "my" opinion about "you."?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't think you'd care about what I _____(think) of you.

- think   [A general statement]
  or
- thought   [at a point in time]
  or
- was thinking   [ongoing in the past].

Other examples:

- Would you care what I think if I hated the movie?
- Would you care what I thought of you then?
- Would you care what I was thinking during the class?

Answer (score 0):

Both "think" and "thought" are possible, as is "am thinking"

The tense carries meaning, and so if you mean "What I in general think about you now" you would use the present.  If you mean "What I thought about out at a past time" then use thought.  The present continuous is unlikely in context, but not ungrammatical: "What I am thinking about you right now (unlike what I generally think about you)"

(In theory "will think", "am going to think" are also possible)